# Can I get a row in procedure/function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a view and a table that are the same. Table is used as a cache because the view takes a lot of time to process.

I have a procedure that is called when the data is changed.

I need to find the row in the view and save it to the table.

Is it a simple way without naming all the columns?

Something like:

```
Declare row FOR SELECT...
INSERT row INTO ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO tab
  SELECT *
    FROM view
   WHERE ...
```

This will insert all rows matching your conditions in where into the table.

Or if you use trigger you could write something like that:

```
INSERT INTO tab (id, ...)
VALUES (new.id, ...);
```